# How to signal sync-complete to the Android SyncManager?

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I was using cancelRequest() from within my SyncAdapter, just before it exits its thread, but I then decided that was only intended to be used by another entity (UI) that wants to cancel a sync in progress (taking too long, oops, etc.)

Now my sync thinks there is always a pending request - which I use to ignore new requests.

The other thing that I have going is a listener thread in a Service that is listening for changes to the **ContactsContract.AUTHORITY** so it can kick off a sync of my aggregation.

UPDATE: This listener thread is leaking.  I am issuing a .stop() when I am done with it, however, there is a handler that I think is staying alive and keeping the service from stopping.

I would like to send SyncResults to some entity (i.e., the SyncManager) that tracks such things for pending, recycle, etc.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SyncResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SyncResult.html) This class is used to communicate the results of a sync operation to the SyncManager. Based on the values here the SyncManager will determine the disposition of the sync and whether or not a new sync operation needs to be scheduled in the future

Comment: OK, The doc is vague and looking at Google source was not very enlightening.  I have looked for sample code for using this class with SyncAdapter, but was not successful.  Can you show some sample code?  I can instantiate and modify, but I don't know how to associate with Account and send to SyncManager?  Does that make sense?

Comment: I have tried setting SyncResult in my application, but I do not see the effect.

Answer (score 10):

To elaborate on shunty's answer with an example:

Here is an [example](https://github.com/maxpower47/PinDroid/blob/development/src/com/pindroid/syncadapter/BookmarkSyncAdapter.java) of setting the SyncResult.  I just use it to set the number of exceptions in the stats field.  The result I see then is that an error icon is displayed for that sync item in the Accounts & sync screen.

Comment: OK - my confusion (concern) is that setting SyncResult, that is an "input" parameter, side-effect programming.  I was hoping that upon conclusion of my onPerformSync, that I could send the SyncResult to the SyncManager or the CP, etc. for it to be recorded.

Comment: I agree, its a crappy thing to do, but that's how it was designed to be used here.